# Searching string in NSArray of custom object using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, nspredicate

I have two classes like below:

```
class City : NSObject{
    var header:String? = nil
    var areas:NSMutableArray? = nil  //Contain array of Area

    //Return array of City objects
    class func generate(cityCount:NSInteger) -> NSMutableArray{...} 
}
```

and

```
class Area : NSObject{
    var title:String? = nil
    var address:String? = nil
}
    //Return array of Area objects
    class func generate(areaCount:NSInteger) -> NSMutableArray {...}
```

Now, I have Array of City like this declared in my viewcontroller:

```
var cities = City.generate(200)
```

and when I search the header inside using NSPredicate it work perfectly

```
let pred = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.header CONTAINS %@",searchString)
let filteredCities = self.cities.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(pred)
```

But when I search the `cities->areas->address` (I want to search address). It is not working. It is always return 0 object. Here what I am trying:

```
let pred = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.areas.address CONTAINS %@",searchString) //name
let filteredCities = (self.cities as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(pred)
```

**EDIT**

I need only the area object that contain matching address. 
I have tried:

```
let pred = NSPredicate(format: "ANY areas.address CONTAINS %@",searchString)
```

This is giving the City object with all area object.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have try like this

```
let pred = NSPredicate(format: "ANY areas.address CONTAINS %@",searchString)
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer but it is crashing the app : *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception **'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "SELF areas.address CONTAINS %@"'**

Comment: Edited. It is filtering city object and return if any area in city matching then returns the whole city object.

Comment: Off course it will return city object because you are filtering City array.

Comment: I agree but I Want to filter address also. If address not contain in area then I dont want area object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118799/discussion-between-gajjar-tejas-and-nirav).

Answer (score 0):

Try this bro,

let pred = NSPredicate(format: "SELF contains[c] %@",searchString)
 let filteredCities = self.area.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(pred)